# How to restrict elements of an ArrayList without using generics

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

Suppose I have an `Employee` class. How can I implement an `ArrayList` only containing `Employee` elements without using generics? That is, without `Arraylist<Employee>`, how can I restrict the `ArrayList` to add only `Employee` objects?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use generics? (just out of curiosity)

Comment: may be some times we dont have java 1.5 .so in some old application we need to restrict the arraylist and in those case we need to implement this logic

Comment: @sartysam: This kind of thinking needs to die. Java has excellent downwards compatibility. In most cases, an App written using any older Java version will run unchanged on the most current JVM without any problems. The few incompatibilities are almost certainly a smaller problem than using a Java version that's been obsolete for 10 years.

Answer (score 8):

Extend ArrayList and customize `add()` and `addAll()` method to check the object being added is `instanceof` `Employee`

Answer (score 8):

You could use a wrapper class that holds a private ArrayList field, say called employeeList, has a

```
public void add(Employee employee) {
   employeeList.add(employee);
}
```

as well as any other necessary methods that would allow outside classes to interact with the ArrayList in a controlled fashion.

I find it much better to use composition for this than inheritance. That way if you wanted to change from an ArrayList to something else, say a LinkedList, or even something completely different, you would have an easier time.

Comment: +1 For the answer that allows compile time checking but unfortunately this means it can't implement `List` with generics out of the picture.

Comment: @Paul: why can't it use a List as the private variable type? I don't see that this would require generics.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - It can; what I'm saying is that your wrapper class can't implement raw `List` - otherwise `add` would take `Object` and we'd be back where we started.

Comment: @Paul: but that's what I'm saying: the variable type of the employeeList variable **can** in fact be List type, and the object referred to by this variable can be an ArrayList. That List takes an Object for its add method is no different from ArrayList, which simply overrides the List's method. This has nothing to do with generics. The public method for the wrapper class would still only take an Employee object, and that's where you'd get your compile-time type checking.

Comment: @Paul: I see what you're saying now. Sorry. I was thinking the type of the private variable and you were talking about the wrapper class itself. Got it, and yes, you are correct. Sorry for my confusion -- it's been a *long* day.

Comment: @Hover No worries - again, nice answer.

Answer (score 8):

You could use [`Collections.checkedList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedList%28java.util.List,%20java.lang.Class%29) - but why would you want to not use generics?

Comment: in one of the old application we are having JDK 1.3 installed.so it doesn't support generics

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the `ArrayList` class and name it something like `EmployeeArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to avoid generics for their own sake, e.g. for compatibility with very old versions of Java, then extending or wrapping ArrayList won't help - you probably want to find or make another array implementation that has the same functionality.

Basically, ArrayList is just a wrapper for a primitive array that copies and pastes its data into a larger array when necessary, so this isn't especially difficult to write from scratch.

Comment: There's no reason to rewrite `ArrayList` entirely - that would achieve the same as the [composition approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11003959/697449) at best.

Comment: I assumed (based on comments) that the author needs to have the option of compiling this code with a Java version so out of date that it doesn't have generics, which (though unfortunate) has happened to me once. But yes, if wrapping or subclassing is an option, either of those should be strongly preferred.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want when you "restrict"? There are two possible places where one could place a restriction: at compile-time or runtime.

Generics is a purely compile-time thing. It helps you write correct code but you can still bypass it and put the wrong type in the array and it won't complain at runtime.

On the other hand, something like `Collections.checkedList()`is a runtime restrictions. It throws an error at runtime when an object of the wrong type comes. But it does not help you at compile-time if you do not have generics.

So the two things are orthogonal, and neither is a replacement for the other. What exactly do you want?